# How to increase Office Ribbon button size ?

Tags: ms-office

I created a "splitButton" for Office Ribbon. I can see only two options for the button size, "normal" and "large". Is there any way to further increase the size of the splitbutton (i.e more than "large"). I looked at this link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd950671(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd950671%28v=office.12%29.aspx) but it was of no help. 
Presently I am using the follwing code:

```
<splitButton id="Button" size="large">
```

Does anybody know how to further increase the size of this button ( or atleast it's width ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot. Office ribbon interface doesn't allow much customization. I guess this is due to the unified look across different solutions. A similar question was answered here: [RibbonButton classes -- can they be extended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375615/ribbonbutton-classes-can-they-be-extended/23381701#23381701)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If its done for the unified look across solution then I suppose we have no way to increase the button size.

Comment: I would also like to ask one more question. Actually I am creating a button which has the content in japanese. But since the width of the button is not enough, Word automatically inserts the newline somewhere in the content. Because of this the content loses its sense. Is there anyway that I can solve this problem ?
[For example you can try this japanese word ( ありがとう ) in google translate. Insert new line at different places and see how the meaning changes. ]